# Application_Error not always firing ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

I am using Routing in my website. What I want to do, is to detect when user enters invalid url and catch error in Application_Error (in Global.asax) and then redirect user to Home page.

For testing I use just one route:

> `routes.MapPageRoute("myroute","Home/{id}/{age}",
>   "~/Home.aspx",false);`

So if I go to `http://testsite/Home/10/25` all works fine.
If I go to `http://testsite/Home/10/25/3443/33/22` server returns "404 Not Found" error. The problem is that Application_Error is **not even firing** here.

BUT if I go to If I go to `http://testsite/Home/10/25/3443/33/22.aspx` then Application_Error **is firing**

Does anyone know why? How can I catch ALL the errors and redirect user to Home page?

P.S. My web.config is:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="Home.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Home.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your application pool in IIS to Integrated Mode

Comment: It is in integrated mode